# What kinds of phonetic or phonological linguistic gaffes are there? (mondegreens, eggcorns, spoonerisms)

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage, errors

I was wondering what other sorts of  phonetics-based linguistic gaffes there are. I don't mean the typical grammatical or syntactic error.

Rather, I mean things like "eggcorns":

> **eggcorn**
>   /ˈɛɡkɔːn/
>   noun.
>   plural noun: eggcorns
>
> - a word or phrase that results from a mishearing or misinterpretation of another, an element of the original being substituted for one which sounds very similar, e.g. *tow the line* instead of *toe the line*.

or "mondegreens":

> **mondegreen**
>   /ˈmɒndəɡriːn/
>   noun.
>
> - a misunderstood or misinterpreted word or phrase resulting from a mishearing of the lyrics of a song.

or "spoonerisms":

> **spoonerism**
>   /ˈspuːnərɪz(ə)m/
>   noun.
>
> - a verbal error in which a speaker accidentally transposes the initial sounds or letters of two or more words, often to humorous effect, as in the sentence *you have hissed the mystery lectures*.

... and  so on. Does anyone know of any others to add to this list?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it doesn't seem to be asking any kind of specific question.

Comment: @Jascol Have made it a bit tighter now ...

Comment: I'm not voting to close this question, because it may be possible to bring it on-topic with some revision of the wording; but as currently expressed it reads like a request for entries to add to an open-ended list—and such list questions are off-topic at this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because list questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Another example is a **[Malapropism](http://tfd.com/malapropism)**:

> - (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) the unintentional misuse of a word by confusion with one of similar sound, esp when creating a ridiculous effect, as in I am not under the affluence of alcohol
> - (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) the habit of misusing words in this manner
> - After Mrs Malaprop in Sheridan's play The Rivals (1775), a character who misused words, from malapropos